# How to implement allowed fields mapping with array object in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two object one for allowed fields another one for overall response. I need to map overall response with allowed fields. Existing code working fine with object but not works with array object fields. Kindly suggest the better solution to implement field mapping.

```
let allowedFields = [
                "id",
                "candidate_id",
                "prospect",
                "location",
                "jobs.id",
                "jobs.name"
            ]


let data = {
                "id": 34050740004,
                "candidate_id": 30068728004,
                "prospect": false,
                "applied_at": "2022-06-10T18:00:52.034Z",
                "rejected_at": null,
                "last_activity_at": "2022-06-10T18:03:05.070Z",
                "location": null,
                "jobs": [
                    {
                        "id": 4354756004,
                        "name": "E2E Testing",
                        "email": "manikandanp97@gmail.com"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 65765,
                        "name": "E2E consensys",
                        "email": "mani.raina@gmail.com"
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Below code is working fine with objects, but field mapping is not working for array objects.

```
async function mapAllowedFields(allowedFields, data) {
            const response = {}
            allowedFields.forEach((loc) => {
                const fields = loc.split(".")
                let conditionObj = data
                let responseObj = response
                for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
                    const key = fields[i]
                    conditionObj = conditionObj?.[key]
                    if (i === fields.length - 1) {
                        responseObj[key] = conditionObj
                    } else if (responseObj[key] === undefined) {
                        responseObj[key] = {}
                    }
                    responseObj = responseObj[key]
                }
            })

            return response
        }
```

Expected results only with allowed fields be like, fields that does not exist in allowed fields array like applied_at, last_activity_at, rejected_at and in jobs array object, email field should be removed from result

```
let result = {
                "id": 34050740004,
                "candidate_id": 30068728004,
                "prospect": false,
                "location": null,
                "jobs": [
                    {
                        "id": 4354756004,
                        "name": "E2E Testing",
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 65765,
                        "name": "E2E consensys",
                    }
                ]
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#syntax

```js
const allowedFields = [
  "id",
  "candidate_id",
  "prospect",
  "location",
  "jobs",
  "name"
];
const txt = [
  {
    "id": 34050740004,
    "candidate_id": 30068728004,
    "prospect": false,
    "applied_at": "2022-06-10T18:00:52.034Z",
    "rejected_at": null,
    "last_activity_at": "2022-06-10T18:03:05.070Z",
    "location": null,
    "jobs": [
      {
        "id": 4354756004,
        "name": "E2E Testing",
        "email": "manikandanp97@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "id": 65765,
        "name": "E2E consensys",
        "email": "mani.raina@gmail.com"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 34050740004,
    "candidate_id": 30068728004,
    "prospect": false,
    "applied_at": "2022-06-10T18:00:52.034Z",
    "rejected_at": null,
    "last_activity_at": "2022-06-10T18:03:05.070Z",
    "location": null,
    "jobs": [
      {
        "id": 4354756004,
        "name": "E2E Testing",
        "email": "manikandanp97@gmail.com"
      },
      {
        "id": 65765,
        "name": "E2E consensys",
        "email": "mani.raina@gmail.com"
      }
    ]
  }
];
const obj = JSON.stringify(txt, allowedFields);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(obj), null, 4);
```

```html
<pre id="demo"></pre>
```

Comment: its not working for array object, in allowed fields jobs.id and jobs.name fields not mapping.